# Installation tools for windows deployment

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

Depends on your experience what are best free installation tools available for windows deployment for both managed and unmanaged deployment ?

Visual studio setup project only works for simple deployment scenario's and it doesnt allow too much customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) is your best bet if you want to build MSI packages. It can be customized to various degrees, from simple modifications to the dialogs to full control over every step of the setup process, it integrates fully with Visual Studio, and it's free and open source.

Be wary that, although the documentation is good and the learning curve (in my opinion) is pretty fast for simple projects, full-fledged personalization requires a moderate to deep understanding of the inner workings of Windows Installer. The excellent [WiX Tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/tutorial) should, however, give you an idea of the possibilities offered by this tool (as well as sample code) without going into too much detail. (Of course, if you want to have an extremely fine-grade control over the setup program, you'll have to resort to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc185688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the end).

Another bonus is that the latest version of WiX offers an integrated bootstrapper as well, so, if you need - for example - to install or upgrade the .NET Framework on the user's machine, you can do it using this single tool (minimal examples are provided in the WiX documentation).

Comment: Are you aware of any good editors for WixToolset ? I tried WixEdit, want to know if there are anything better than WixEdit

Comment: @Ankit See http://sharpsetup.eu/ and http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried these editors, I have just taken the links from a related question on SO and an entry on Rob Mensching's blog.) I, however, suggest you to use an editor only to design the installer interface and to use an XML editor (or Visual Studio) for everything else, as learning the gory details definitely proves useful to integrate the setup into your program (e.g. if you want to install some features on demand or perform auto-repair, just like Microsoft Office does).

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at

**[InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php#features)**